# How can we know the definition of $\bar{\phi}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

If $W$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$ stable under the linear transformation $\varphi$(i.e., $\varphi(W) \subseteq W$), show that $\varphi$ induces linear transformations $\varphi |_{W}$ on $W$ and $\bar{\varphi}$ on the quotient vector space $V/W.$

I do not know what definition should I use of  $\bar{\phi}$ and why, could someone clarify for me please?

**Edit:**
The definition is given online in many resources, which is $\bar{\varphi} (v + W) = \varphi(v) + W$ but I do not know why this is the correct definition.

What are we looking for in the definition?

Comment: The elements of $V/W$ looks like $v + W$. What do you think that would be a natural way to define $\bar{\varphi}(v+W)$?

Comment: @jjagmath The definition is given online in many resources, which is $\bar{\varphi} (v + W) = \varphi(v) + W$ but I do not know why this is the correct definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define
$$\bar{\varphi}:V/W\to V/W,\ \ v+W\mapsto \varphi(v)+W.$$

The essential thing we need to check is, if $v_1+W=v_2+W$, then they should also be assigned the same value under $\varphi$, that is we should show $\bar{\varphi}(v_1+W)=\bar{\varphi}(v_2+W)$. That is:

We need to show $v_1+W=v_2+W\implies \varphi(v_1)+W=\varphi(v_2)+W$.

In fact $v_1+W=v_2+W$ $\iff$ $v_1-v_2\in W$, while $\varphi(v_1)+W=\varphi(v_2)+W$ $\iff$ $\varphi(v_1)-\varphi(v_2)\in W$ $\iff$ $\varphi(v_1-v_2)\in W$ $\impliedby v_1-v_2\in W$, since by hypothesis $\varphi(W)\subseteq W$.

Comment: But why we should use this definition? Is it by the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: @Secretly So you are asking why we define $\bar{\varphi}$ exactly by that function:
$$ \bar{\varphi}:V/W\to V/W,\ \ v+W\mapsto \varphi(v)+W.$$
In fact "induce" is a not totally formal word. It means "A construction naturally comes to our mind : $\cdots$". So you can think this definition as a convention.

Comment: By the way, I left it to you to check $\bar{\varphi}$ is linear, which should be quite easy, almost restating the definition of operations on quotient space.

Comment: for your first comment yes that is exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: for your last comment, yes I know how to do this, do not worry about it and thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

- $\phi$ is a map from $V$ to $V$.
- $v + W$ is a subset of $V$

A very natural thing is to look at the image of $v + W = \{ v + w : w \in W\}$ under the map $\phi$.

$$ \phi(v + W) := \{ \phi(v + w) :  w \in W\} = \phi(v) + \phi(W) \subset \phi(v) + W$$ where we used $\phi(W) \subset W$.

This does make it quite obvious that defining  $\bar \phi$ as
$$ \bar \phi : V/W \to V/W :  v + W \mapsto \phi(v) + W$$
is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The definition makes for a pretty commutative diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
W @>>> V @>>> V/W\\
@V{\varphi|_W}VV @V{\varphi}VV @VV{\overline{\varphi}}V\\
W @>>> V @>>> V/W
\end{CD}$$

Here the horizontal arrows are inclusion and projection.